# Definition of a file system

Tags: filesystems, terminology

I'm trying to understand what is exactly a file system. I found various answers on the web including the ones provided here: [Is a file system just the layout of folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/365599/is-a-file-system-just-the-layout-of-folders).
While these answers provide valuable informations, it's still unclear to me whether a file system is:
a - A collection of data structures (*inodes, master file table, file allocation table, ...*) that index files and directories .
b - A collection of data structures that index files and directories **and** the file tree.
c - A file tree (*mounting a file system, mounting a network file system, the /proc file system*).

Comment: Folders are pretty much virtual in windows, add almost nothing to the data payload. Learn more here>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/365599/is-a-file-system-just-the-layout-of-folders

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's still unclear for me.
I would like to know if what's called the file system is:
a - the data structures alone (MFT, Inodes, ...) that index the directories and folders.
b - the data structures (MFT, inodes) and the file tree. 
c - the file tree.